# view controller not refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a view controller with a collection view, when the user click on the cell, the app segues into a view controller that has a table view of all the post the user has.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "userprofile" {
let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
     let postsForUser: [[String: Any]] = posts.filter {
                        guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else {
                            return false
                        }
                        return post["uid"] as? String == uid
                        } as! [[String : Any]]
                    print("postForUser = \(postsForUser)")
                    vc.posts = postsForUser //vc.posts should be [[String: Any]]
                }}
```

In the UsersProfileViewController the cells are populated in CellForRowAt

```
 let post = self.posts![(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]


        cell.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
        cell.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
        cell.ISBN10.text = post["ISBN10"] as? String
        cell.ISBN13.text = post["ISBN13"] as? String
        cell.CoverType.text = post["CoverType"] as? String
        cell.Price.text = post["Price"] as? String
```

Everytime the view appears I want to reload the table view.

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        let indexPath = self.selectedIndex

        let cell:ProfileTableViewCell? = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath! as IndexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell        
        if(vcUserBook == true) // from EditPostViewController
        {


            let post = self.posts![(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]

            cell?.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
            cell?.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
            cell?.ISBN10.text = post["ISBN10"] as? String
            cell?.ISBN13.text = post["ISBN13"] as? String
            cell?.CoverType.text = post["CoverType"] as? String
            cell?.Price.text = post["Price"] as? String


        }

        }
```

But when I run it, the app crashes when I click on the collection cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t initiate a `cell` as you do in your `viewWillAppear`. The tableView has not finished it´s drawing yet and that´s why you get the error.

All this part from `viewWillAppear` needs to be done in `cellForRowAt`:

```
let indexPath = self.selectedIndex
let cell:ProfileTableViewCell? = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath! as IndexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell        
if(vcUserBook == true) // from EditPostViewController {
    let post = self.posts![(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]

    cell?.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
    cell?.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
    cell?.ISBN10.text = post["ISBN10"] as? String
    cell?.ISBN13.text = post["ISBN13"] as? String
    cell?.CoverType.text = post["CoverType"] as? String
    cell?.Price.text = post["Price"] as? String
}
```

In your `viewWillAppear` you should only do `TableView.reloadData()` and handle the cells in your `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: I did that but it the table view does not reload every time the view appears

Comment: For example, when I click a button in the cell, it allows me to go to another controller and edit the cell and once the edit has been sent to firebase, it unwinds the segue. But when I unwind the segue, the tableview is not updated. That is why I am trying to update the table view everytime the view appears

Comment: `viewWillAppear` will always be called when you go to a view. Make sure that you have an updated datasource (your data model you´re using to populate the tableView) before you do `tableView.reloadData()`. That´s important, so get all data needed and then reload your table.

Comment: when i included tableView.reloadData() in cellForRowAt it didn't update but it get printing the details of the table view over and over again

Comment: In your `UsersProfileViewControllers` `viewWillAppear` before you do `tableView.reloadData()` make sure that `self.posts` is updated with the relevant data. Otherwise you won´t load the new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reload data

`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

YourTableView.reloadData()  }`

Comment: Is there an error message? Or it’s just doesn’t refresh the table data?

Comment: theres an error message on  `let cell:ProfileTableViewCell? = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath! as IndexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell` saying unexpectedly found nil

Comment: Are you trying to reload whole table? Because based on your code you tried to reload just one cell. And what is a outcome of running my code, do you see a clean table or what?

Comment: I want to reload the whole table. I don't see a clean table because based on my code, it crashes before it segues to the userprofileviewcontroller

Comment: I understand that. I mean because it’s not crushing your app do you able to see the table?

Comment: This is what I am trying to accomplish: For example, when I click a button in the cell, it allows me to go to another controller and edit the cell and once the edit has been sent to firebase, it unwinds the segue. But when I unwind the segue, the tableview is not updated. That is why I am trying to update the table view everytime the view appears

Comment: So I do see the table but it is not updated with the new edit

Comment: You can try to add debugPrint in your CellForCow function. To make sure that you’re actually getting the new date at the moment when you call reloadData() and to make sure that it’s getting called at all